# Navigating in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid

Hi I'm new in creating hybrid applications using ionic framework 
I have created my app's sign-in page using blank starter and it works well
the problem arises when i try to navigate to next page (i.e)by clicking sign-in button

app.js file

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "app/layout/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .controller('AppCtrl',function($scope){
    })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/layout');
});

index.html file
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
  
  <script src=app/layout/app1.js></script>
  <script src=js/controllers.js></script>
</head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
     
      <ion-content>
 <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Username</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Password</span>
              <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="padding">
            <button nav-clear class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="LogIn(user)">
              Sign-In
            </button>
            <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="ion-balanced">
            </ion-nav-bar>   
            <ion-nav-view name="Documents"</ion-nav-view>
            <script src="app/layout/menu.html" type="text/ng-template"></script>   
          </ion-pane>
          </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  
<script>//<![CDATA[
document.write('<script src="//' + (location.hostname || 'localhost') + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"><\/script>')
//]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain the problem in more detail. Which line of code. What error is seen, show logs.

Comment: I cant see any error in it but i could'nt navigate ?????

Comment: You must include the ionicApp module inside the starter module.

Comment: This is the error
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line: `angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])`

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to ionicApp seems correct.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
```

One thing i noticed, you are missing a route for '/app/layout

This may help you. http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/CbBsA